# Issue regarding possible until loop in script

Tags: bash, awk

I'm fairly new to all this stuff so I do apologise if I'm being silly! I've had a look around but can't seem to find anything that's solving this for me. I'm learning as I go at the moment so would really appreciate some help!

I'm currently making a script, within part of the script I need to run `su (username)` then have the user type in the password. Is there any way to have the su command keep on being run until a specific username is detected in the output after running the following command -

```
ps aux | grep bash | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq
```

I'd like it to keep trying to substitute user until they get it correct (or cancel out of the script) or at least more than 3 times and then automatic logout.

I was thinking using the 'until' loop or something perhaps?

```
(until....(the output of command) = (username) run su (username))
```

Sorry if I've not explained myself very well, hope you guys have got the jist of what I'm after!

I really appreciate your help in advance :)

Cheers, Jack :)

--------------EDIT-------------------------EDIT-------------------------EDIT-----------
I can't post an answer to my own question yet due to my rep. Here's what I wrote out though. (apologies for the mess here guys :S)

Hey everyone,

I think I actually just got it working! Using the following script ---

```
until [ "ps aux | grep bash | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq" = "(username)" ] 
  do

     echo "Please enter password for (username)"
     su (username)

  done
```

Seems pretty simple now that it's working. Before it kept not recognising certain parts of the script like 'do' but I guess I just needed the syntax and format to be correct.

Let me know if there's anything I can do to make it better of course, but I really appreciate everyone's suggestions! :) I'll look into having it only run su a certain number of times maybe but we will see!

Thanks,

Jack :)

Comment: Sorry I really don't get the jist :/ could you try re-wording your second paragraph and showing the code you are currently using

Comment: Do you really mean to use `su` or `sudo`?

Comment: That `ps...uniq` pipeline can be abbreviated to just `ps aux | awk '/bash/ && !seen[$1]++'` but you might want to do `man pgrep`.

Comment: You could use grep to see if the username appears in the output. The exit status of grep could be your loop condition.

Comment: konsolebox - As far as I know I need to change to a certain account before I can run sudo. Otherwise it would probably be a bit simpler :(
 
EdMorton - That's awesome, I'll take a look! :) 

GavinSmith - Yeah..that's pretty much what I'm trying to do I think. Use grep to check the output to see if the username is there. But I'm getting a bit held up on the syntax and format of the whole thing to be honest!

Sorry guys, I tried to do the @ thing but I can only do it to one person it seems.

Comment: You want to keep giving them the option of entering the password for `su` until they get the password right and get to the `su` user's shell?

Comment: @EtanReisner - ah, if only ATMs worked that way :-)....

Comment: @EtanReisner - Yeah, pretty much! Think I just sorted it out actually. I added it on to the bottom of my original post as I can't answer my own question yet due to rep :S 

It's not perfect but seems to do the job! Any improvements maybe?

Comment: You sure `"ps aux | grep bash | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq"` is what you need, not `"$(ps aux | grep bash | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq)"`?

Comment: Also it's a good thing if you run `sleep` at least 1 to 5 secs before every loop to not let it burn your CPU.

Comment: I'm unsure how this is supposed to work in practice since I wouldn't expect su to return (and your script to continue) until after the su shell finishes. That being said I think my expected operation gives you a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @konsolebox Hmmm...very possibly. I'll take a look and give it a try! And that's a good point indeed, will add something like that in for sure. Thanks!

Comment: @EtanReisner That's very true..that's the issue I'm having now. Might just have to use    su (username) -c 
then the commands instead. Didn't think of that before...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, and I don't have a way to test this assumption at the moment unfortunately, that su returns non-zero when the password entry fails, and assuming it returns zero when the password is correct and the su shell exits cleanly then you should be able to use the return code of the su itself to determine whether to loop again. Something like the following.

```
while echo "Please enter password for (username)"; ! su (username); do
    ....
done
```

Comment: That's a really good point, would definitely make it much easier and cleaner if I can find out how to do that. I'll have a look and see if I can get it working like that. Really appreciate everyones help!